# Increment of global variable in google app script isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

How to increment my global variable 'currentstep' in Google App Script. The third if statement, I used currentstep++ but it doesn't increase as it stayed at 2. Furthermore, I had tried currentstep += 1; and currentstep = currentstep + 1; Both methods don't work as well.

```
function check_command(data){
  var text = data.message.text;
  
  if(text == "/start" || text == "/start"){
    currentstep = 1;
    return;
  }
  
  if (text == "/survey" || text == "/survey"){
    currentstep = 2;
    return;
  }
  if (text){
    currentstep++;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on what your `if` conditions actually do? It's a bit hard to infer the reason for them. Also, have you tried debugging with console outputs to see which  `if` block the code actually runs?

Comment: Sorry, how do i use the console outputs to debug? This is my first time coding this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact APIs that you are using (with Google Apps Script), but usually you just add short debugging messages (via something like `console.log("I'm in the 'start' if-block!")`) to the code, and then check the output window, terminal, or similar.

Comment: Based on the code snippet you provided, if the script enters any of the first two `if` blocks, it will never enter the third one, since the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) ends the function execution. If you don't what that to happen, you should remove the `return` from the first two `if` blocks. Also, there's no need to add a `return` at the end of your function if you don't want to return any value. Can you please check whether that's the cause of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In google apps script every time you make a function call the global variable get reinitialized.  So typically it's better to use PropertiesService or CacheService for global parameters that you wish to change from one execution to another.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions like this:

```
if (text == "/start" || text == "/start") { ... }
```

Have little sense. They are equal with this:

```
if (text == "/start") { ... }
```

So your function can be boiled down to this:

```
function check_command(data) {
    var text = data.message.text;

    if (text == "/start")  { currentstep = 1; return }
    if (text == "/survey") { currentstep = 2; return }
    if (text)              { currentstep++ }
}
```

And it works fine by itself, as far as I can tell.

Here is a test:

```js
function check_command(data) {
    var text = data.message.text;

    if (text == "/start")  { currentstep = 1; return }
    if (text == "/survey") { currentstep = 2; return }
    if (text)              { currentstep++ }
}

var currentstep = 0;
var data = {message: {text: ""}};

var texts = [
    , 
    "", 
    false, 
    "/start", 
    "/survey", 
    "", 
    , 
    "aaa",
    "/survey",
    123,
    "/start",
    ""
]

for (let txt of texts) {
    data.message.text = txt;
    check_command(data);
    console.log("currentstep = " + currentstep + " for '" + txt + "'");
}
```

Probably @Cooper is right. You're doing something fancy that we can't know from your question. Are you running the script several times and trying to keep the global value between the runs?

**Update**

If you suspect that the problem is a global variable you can modify your function to avoid using the global variable within the function:

```
function check_command(data, counter) {
    var text = data.message.text;

    if (text == "/start")  return = 1;
    if (text == "/survey") return = 2;
    if (text) counter++;

    return counter;
}
```

And call the function this way:

```
currentstep = check_command(data, currentstep);
```

Comment: Hi. My code is: When I type /survey, it will update my global variable to 'currentstep' = 2 which will run another function and post a question, "how are you?" in my telegram bot. The script will wait for me to type any text, afterwards run my if statement when any text is typed in. And when a text is entered, it will  then update my global variable into 'currentstep' = 3 to run another function and post another question.

Basically i am trying to create a mini survey in telegram bot.

Comment: Sorry, I know next to nothing about Telegram bots. But I'm sure your problem is not within this code. By the way, in most cases you can avoid global variables if you will pass all data in a function as arguments and return a result data from a function as an object or array.